# Get array of related objects django

Tags: django, django-2.0

I have this models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
```

And

```
class Group(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name = "projects")
```

I want to be able to retrieve projects groups.

I tried something like this:

```
print(project.groups)
```

but got an error:

> 'Project' object has no attribute 'group'

What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've set `related_name = "projects"` you should use `projects` attribute for back relation:

```
print(project.projects)
```

In simple words [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) argument allows you to specify reverse lookup.

Comment: Note though it doesn't really make sense to call it `projects`, you should make it `groups` instead.